# Error in receiving JSON by Buffered Reader

Tags: java, android, json, sockets, gson

My Server is sending some JSON String to my Android Client, but some errors occured. Please Help:

My Server is trying to send the following text to my android client 
Server Output: ( 2D String Array)

```
[
    [
      "testingg",
      "3",
      "24:df:6a:e7:47:3c",
      "f8:e7:1e:1e:21:58",
      "f8:e7:1e:1d:fd:3c"
    ],
    [
      "moreee",
      "4",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:35:fe:38",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08",
      "24:c9:a1:36:04:38"
    ],
    [
      "lailailai",
      "4",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08",
      "24:c9:a1:35:fe:38",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48"
    ],
    [
      "tryyyy",
      "2",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:35:fe:38"
    ],
    [
      "testyyy",
      "2",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08"
    ],
    [
      "hahaha",
      "3",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:35:fe:38",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08"
    ],
    [
      "ehyyy",
      "2",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08"
    ],
    [
      "offlinet",
      "2",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "e8:de:27:5b:a2:ea"
    ],
    [
      "opop",
      "4",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:02:98",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:02:98"
    ],
    [
      "tt",
      "5",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08",
      "24:c9:a1:35:fe:38",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08"
    ],
    [
      "Input",
      "6",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:35:fe:38",
      "70:8b:cd:b3:17:2c",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "70:8b:cd:b3:17:2c",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48"
    ],
    [
      "cekkk",
      "5",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:08",
      "24:c9:a1:35:fe:38",
      "24:c9:a1:36:05:78",
      "24:c9:a1:36:03:48"
    ],
    [
      "oo",
      "5",
      "24:df:6a:e7:47:3c",
      "e8:de:27:5b:a2:ea",
      "70:8b:cd:b3:17:2c",
      "f4:f2:6d:d1:20:20",
      "e8:50:8b:f3:a9:2a"
    ]
    ]
```

** Client Code:** ( Receiving entity )

```
  public class databrowsing extends AppCompatActivity {
  Socket myclient = null;
  private String jsonString = "";
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_databrowsing);
    socketHandler CLIENT = new socketHandler();
    myclient = CLIENT.getSocket();

    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(myclient.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.println("OnlinePositiongforIndoorPositioning");

   new receiveJson().execute(myclient);

 }




private class receiveJson extends AsyncTask< Socket,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Socket... params ){
        myclient=params[0];
        try {
            StringBuffer buildString=new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myclient.getInputStream()));
            while((jsonString=in.readLine())!=null){
                buildString.append(jsonString);
            }
            return jsonString;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        String[][] tableconfig = gson.fromJson(jsonString, String[][].class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tableconfig));
    }
}
```

**Error Logcat of the Android Studio:**

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
 at com.utm.jeechunhian.indoorpositioning.databrowsing$receiveJson$override.doInBackground(databrowsing.java:53)
 at com.utm.jeechunhian.indoorpositioning.databrowsing$receiveJson$override.access$dispatch(databrowsing.java)
 at com.utm.jeechunhian.indoorpositioning.databrowsing$receiveJson.doInBackground(databrowsing.java:0)

 at com.utm.jeechunhian.indoorpositioning.databrowsing$receiveJson.doInBackground(databrowsing.java:44)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
```

Comment: Can you show me your socket connection? Looks like you left a connection open after a request and that is why you are getting ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Comment: I have uploaded the full code of the client side current Activity, please advise, Thank you.